Access One80 router via console connection using Adafruit FT232H
I have an old One80 router. I am following this blog post to try and connect via the console port to reset it as I don't have any details for it.
The documentation I could find specified:

Serial parameters: 9600 bps, 8 bits data, No parity, 1 Stop bit, No flow control

It also has a proprietary pin out for the console cable. I therefore sacrificed an old Cisco cable and used some female to female jumper wires to attach it to an adafruit FT232H. However, if I try and connect using screen just prints out gibberish. I have tried both:
screen /dev/tty.usbserial-140 9600,cs8,-parenb,-cstopb
and
stty -F /dev/tty.usbserial-140 9600 cs8 -cstopb -parenb
screen /dev/tty.usbserial-140

I also tested the continuity from the header pins on the FT232H to the RJ45 connector using a multimeter and it was fine.
If I use a bus pirate, by also specifying:
receive polarity -  Idle 0, Open drain (H=Hi-Z, L=GND) and Transparent bridge it will properly print out the boot logs and show a login prompt.
Nothing is printed when I type at this point though and the Enter key doesn't change anything either. I have tried turning on local echo via stty and using minicom instead of screen and specifying it in it's configuration but that does not fix it.
I have two questions.

Is it possible to specify the additional options that are set on the bus pirate when using screen? I had a look at the man pages for screen and stty but couldn't see anything. Are they bus pirate specific options?
How can I troubleshoot with the bus pirate (or depending on the answer to 1 with screen) further to be able to reset the device or even attempt to enter credentials?


If the device has an RS-232 port, you cannot connect to it with a TTL level UART chip.
You need at least a RS-232 transceiver, or just buy a USB-to-RS232 adapter and then do a custom DE-9 to 8P8C cable (RJ-45 is not the name of the connector and also not the name of a port that uses RS-232, in fact, there is even no thing that is officially called as RJ-45).

Good answer... "If it looks like a duck, swims like a duck, and quacks like a duck, then it probably is a duck." That's not the case here.

Thank you @Justme, that prompted me to go and read about the differences and have learnt more than just what I needed to achieve the objective. It was also very straightforward once I used a USB to DB9 cable connected to a modified Cisco cable.
